# Native ASP.NET JSON objects to work same as with Python

Tags: asp.net, python, json

Is there any way to work with JSON objects natively on ASP.NET 4.5 like it works Python. With Python it's very east to get a JSON from MongoDB, send it to the template and iterate through the results without casting at all. Is there any way to do it with ASP.NET, any extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using nuget you can download a json dll (newton) that will help you serialise and deserialise json very easily so you can work with it.

Check http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx